# How to implement badgeville in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Can anyone tell me how to implement `badgeville` in ruby on rails?

EDIT:
how can I apply this on ruby on rails?

https://github.com/badgeville/badgeville-ruby

Comment: when you asks a question, you should be give more details about the question. links and specially what you have done so far (like your researches etc..) then only ppl will be able to help you..

Comment: can anyone help me how to apply this.

https://github.com/badgeville/badgeville-ruby

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this particular gem work, but normally it should work with following steps

1. create a file called 'badgeville.rb' inside app/config/initializers
2. add the following code to badgeville.rb

   BadgevilleBerlin::Config.conf(
             :host_name => "http://example.com",
             :api_key   => MY_API_KEY)
3. restart
4. then you should be able to use the following commands inside your
   controllers/ models

   Ex:

   new_site = BadgevilleBerlin::Site.new(
                 :name       => "My Website",
                 :url        => "mydomain.com",
                 :network_id => MY_NETWORK_ID )
               success = new_site.save

Comment: It doesn't work.. I having an error and it said, `..config/initializers/badgeville.rb:3:in <module:Ba
dgevilleBerlin>: uninitialized constant BadgevilleBerlin::Config (NameError)`

Comment: did u install the badgeville-ruby gem

Comment: yes I am.. and actually I already configured all the requirement.. Host, and API key, etc. in my gem.

Comment: try adding require 'badgeville_berlin' on top of your badgeville.rb file